# Google Smart Lock suggestions problem

Tags: password

How I can delete old profiles from that list? In my saved passwords I don't have this, only 1 saved for VK. Same problem in tinder app too, always suggested use my old number and couple other apps. It so annoying. How fix it?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open any web browser and navigate it to https://passwords.google.com/.
2. Enter your Google sign-in information to sign-in to your Google account as usual.
3. You will see settings for turning off or on the SmartLock Passwords,
   and the Auto Sign-in option for SmartLock.
4. These options would
   be a list of all the saved passwords, whether saved through the
   Chrome browser or through the SmartLock feature in Android.
5. Android Smart Lock Passwords Passwords are masked by default for privacy
   reasons. You can reveal the masked passwords by clicking/touching
   the small eye graphic.
6. In order to delete one of these passwords,
   you can just click on the small cross shown next to that password.
7. The passwords are deleted without any confirmation, so be careful
       not to delete some password that you have forgotten about.